# C++ : Accessor and Mutator Functions

Tags: c++

Is it really necessary to use accessor and mutator functions in member functions of a class? That is, instead of directly referencing the member variables of that class, we call a getter to get the value...

I don't see the necessity or reasoning of using accessors or mutators when its within a member function of that same class.

Oh, by the way, these member variables are private.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not necessary.

It's just a convention, nothing more. Having these kinds of accessor methods -- and using them even in other class methods -- might help make future changes to classes easier to implement, but this is not strictly required.

Answer (score 1):

Well, no, it's not. But it does provide you with a lot of extra possibilities. Especially ones that you'll only realise later.

First of all, you can make them `virtual`. So any subclass, can implement the setter and the getter in their own way.

Secondly, you can decide later: "oh, whenever that value changes i nead to do something." Just add one line of code to your setter, instead of `ctrl-f`-ing your entire project or whatever.

And just-in-time updates of course. Imagine there is this value that requires quite a bit of calculation to arrive at. And half the time you don't even nead it. just calculate it in your getter, remember the result for the future, and return it. Now you only calculate it if you actually need it.

So yes, you can make values private, but you have to be really sure that you won't regret it later.

---

just for fun, have a look at "qt properties".